# Openwhisk alternative to IBM?

Tags: cloud-computing

IBM is deprecating Cloud Functions, its Openwhisk Functions as a service offering.

Is there anybody else proposing a similar offering?

I know I could use a generic hosting service and install Openwhisk there but I am looking for a drop-in replacement of IBM cloud functions, where autoscaling and downscaling is managed etc

I know I could migrate to other Functions as a Service offering, not using Openwhisk, but I am looking for a solution which would not require adapting code, just changing the target host.

Does anything of the sort exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Digital Oceans Functions](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/functions) - DO [acquired Nimbella](https://www.digitalocean.com/blog/nimbella-joins-the-digitalocean-family), which was a startup founded by an [ex-IBMer](https://rabbah.io/) who helped create Openwhisk.

Comment: You can improve your answer by providing some features or specs on it.

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH!! I had searched for hours and hadn't found anything, I can't believe it. Thanks to you I ran into this article, which also mentions Adobe I/O and Naver: https://openwhisk.blog/post/advocate/openwhisk-portable-serverless/